# ¿Se puede importar props de otro componente?

Tags: reactjs

Si importamos un objeto o un json podemos importarlo y enviarlo por las props de un Componente. Ejemplo:

```
    import Componente from './componente.js'
    import items from './menu.js'
```

luego en la clase App

```
    render() {
      return(
        Componente menu={items}
      )
    }
```

Esto lo conozco. Pero ¿Hay forma de exportar los props de un componente a otro componente?

Si tengo el mismo ejemplo pero importo un nuevo componente Menu.js y deseo que cuando de click en uno de esos menúes, en el componente Component.js renderice algo. Y la mecánica sería enviar un estado de Menu.js a Componente.js.

Comment: En la mayoría de casos, la respuesta que te ha dado @MarcosMartínez funciona bien. Sin embargo, cuando la estructura de los componentes es muy compleja, por ejemplo, deseas sincroniza componentes que no son ni siquiera hermanos, es mejor aislar el estado usando Redux o Mobx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, **si**, no solo es posible enviar información tanto de las `props` como del `state` de un componente **padre** a **su/s hijo/s** sino que es el enfoque de React propone.

El  manejo de datos en React es **jerárcico** y **unidireccional** (top-down), es decir:

1. El estado debe ser **conocido y modificado por el elemento superior en común** a los elementos hijos. Por mas info ver [**React docs: Lifting state up**](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)
2. La información **pasa de un elemento padre a un elemento hijo**, el `state` es utilizado para data **volátil y mutable**, mientras que las `props` son datos **inmutables**. El flujo correcto es que un padre envié su `state` como `prop` de su/s hijo/s, de modo que al cambiar el `state` en el padre, se invoque el `render()` y afecte los `props` de los hijos. Es decir, los hijos modifican su comportamiento y renderizado según el estado del padre (almacenado en sus `props`) y su propio estado interno.

**Ejemplo**: pasando desde el elemento padre hasta los elementos hoja las `props` color y `size`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

<sup>*Imágen extraída de: https://www.kirupa.com/react/transferring_properties.htm*</sup>

---

**Mini ejemplo:**

He implementado un mini ejemplo para visualizar esto, que basicamente se compone de una página pricipal y un menú de navegación (*muy feos por cierto*):

**`<Menu />` component:**

- Mantiene en sus props un listado de elementos a mostrar, recibidos del padre
- Mantiene en sus props un booleano `showItems`
- [**Renderiza condicionalmente**](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) los `items` según la propiedad anterior

**`<Page />` component:**

- Mantiene en su estado si las acciones de la página están habilitadas o no
- Crea componente `<Menu />` indicando su prop `showItems` para renderizado condicional
- Tiene una funcion handler para habilitar/desabilitar acciones, la cual invoca `this.setState()` y por ende de haber cambios dispara el `render()` (comportamiento estandar de React)

```js
class Menu extends React.Component{

  /* renders the items conditionally */
  render(){
    return (
    <div> 
        <h3> {this.props.title} </h3>
        {this.props.showItems && (<ul> {this.props.items} </ul>)}
    </div>) ;
  }
  
}

class Page extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     // set initial state with enableActions = true  to make the checkbox checked by default
     this.state ={enableActions: true};
  }

  render(){
      {/* creates <button> for each action item */}
      let actions = this.props.actions.map((item)=>{return <li><button> {item} </button></li> });
      return(
        <div>
          <span>Enable menu actions </span>
           {/* checkbox that changes the state  */}
          <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.enableActions} onChange ={this.handleChange}/>
           {/* (Parent State -> Child prop) - create <Menu /> passing state "enableActions" as "showItems" property */}
          <Menu title="Navigation bar" items = {actions} showItems= {this.state.enableActions} />
        </div>
      );
  }
  
  handleChange(e){
    {/* updates state with the current checked value of the checkbox */}
    this.setState({enableActions : e.target.checked});
  }
  
}

let items = ["Help","Login","About us"];
ReactDOM.render(<Page actions = {items} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

button{
  background: #bcd4e6;
  border: 1px solid #4c8dbd;
  color: #4c8dbd;
  width: 70px;
}

h3{
  background: #0095ff;
  color: white;
   margin: 0;
}

ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id = "root">

<div>
```