# Como anidar componentes a través de funciones/métodos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo `React`, y me he encontrado con ciertas situaciones las cuales no se como resolver, en este caso, el como anidar componentes, para que las funciones que estén en uno, se ejecuten luego de terminar las de otro. A continuación, planteare el problema.

#### Componente_1.jsx (Padre)

```
class Componente_1 extends Component{

    constructor(){    

    } 

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 

            </div> 
        )
    }

    funcion_uno(variable){       
       //ejecutar algo 
       //operaciones, asignaciones, etc
    } 
}

export default Componente_1;
```

#### Componente_2.jsx (Hijo)

```
class Componente_2 extends Component{

    constructor(){    

    } 

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 

            </div> 
        )
    }

    funcion_dos(variable){       
       //ejecutar algo 
       //operaciones, asignaciones, etc
       //Ejecutar la función 3
    } 
}

export default Componente_2;
```

#### Componente_3.jsx (Hijo)

```
class Componente_3 extends Component{

    constructor(){    

    } 

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 

            </div> 
        )
    }

    funcion_Tres(variable){       
       //ejecutar algo 
       //operaciones, asignaciones, etc
    } 
}

export default Componente_3;
```

Por ejemplo, tenemos el `Componente_2` y el `Componente_3`, en mi caso amobis son componentes hijos del `Componente_1`. Lo que busco es que al ejecutar la `funcion_dos` haciendo uso de la opción **click** a un botón, o cualquiera que yo desee, pero debo ejecutar dicha función.

Luego, de ejecutar dicha función, quisiera saber, como ejecutar la `funcion_Tres` que esta alojada en el `Componente_3`, luego que la `funcion_uno` termine de ejecutarse.

***Nota:*** *En el ejemplo estoy obviando los `import` que se hacen a `react`, `react-dom`, y cualquier otro complemento que necesite.*

Answer (score 2):

A grandes razgos sin entrar en mucho detalle, tenes que tener en cuenta dos cosas

1) React esta orientado a componentes, por ende, tus componentes pueden ser reutilizados en otros componentes. En este caso, tu Componente_1 puede estar compuesto (valga la redundancia) de Componente_2.

2) Props: Cada componente puede recibir N props, las props son recibidas del padre y son elementos que deberían ser inmutables. Pueden ser funciones, variables, data, etc

Comento como he modificado tu codigo para lograr lo que deseas:

1. Componente 1 retorna un div que contiene a Componente_2
2. Componente 2 recibe como prop un elemento el cual llame callback. La idea de esta prop es que sea una funcion a ejecutar en el momento en que desee.
3. Componente 2 renderiza un boton cuyo onClick dispara funcion_2. Funcion 2 ejecuta como primera instrucción la función recibida como property. Para que reconozca this.props como las propiedades de la clase es necesario bindear el scope de la palabra clave this al scope de la clase (eso lo hice en el constructor), de lo contrario, this valdrá la función_2

```js
class Componente_1 extends React.Component{



    render(){
        return(
            <div> 
              <Componente_2 callback={this.funcion_uno}/>
            </div> 
        )
    }

    funcion_uno(variable){       
        console.log("Ejecucion funcion 1");

    } 
}

class Componente_2 extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
      super();
      this.funcion_dos = this.funcion_dos.bind(this);
    }
 
    render(){
        return(
            <div> 
              <button onClick={this.funcion_dos}>Click me </button>
            </div> 
        )
    }

    funcion_dos(variable){      
       this.props.callback();
       console.log("Ejecucion funcion 2");
    } 
}


ReactDOM.render(<Componente_1 />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id = "root">

<div>
```

**Edit**: Utilizando refs, enfoque bottom up. Lectura recomendada: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```js
class Componente_1 extends React.Component{

     constructor(){
      super();
      this.funcion_uno = this.funcion_uno.bind(this);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 
              <button onClick={this.funcion_uno}>Click me </button>
               <Componente_2 ref="child1"/>
            </div> 
        )
    }

    funcion_uno(variable){       
        console.log("Ejecucion funcion 1");
        this.refs.child1.funcion_dos();

    } 
}

class Componente_2 extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
      super();
    }
 
    render(){
        return(
            <div> 
              Hola soy el componente 2
            </div> 
        )
    }

    funcion_dos(variable){      
       console.log("Ejecucion funcion 2");
    } 
}


ReactDOM.render(<Componente_1 />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id = "root">

<div>
```

Comment: Respuesta buena, según veo aquí, estas ejecutando las dos funciones al mismo tiempo, pero veo que el orden, es que primero, ejecutas la `funcion_dos`, para luego esta ejecutase la `funcion_uno`, si no es así házmelo saber.

Comment: Exacto. Pero abstraete de la numeración de tus componentes y funciones. Lo que quieres basicamente es un componente padre y un componente hijo. El componente padre le indica al hijo "ejecutame esta función que te paso como property", y el hijo, debe saber manejar sus properties. Edite la respuesta con otro enfoque posible.

Comment: No lo he probado, pero debe funcionar, gracias, podrías echarle un ojo a otra pregunta que hice, que me esta matando. [Como enviar/retornar parametros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148501/como-enviar-retornar-par%C3%A1metros-entre-dos-o-mas-componentes)

Comment: Pruebalo y cualquier cosa vuelve por aqui!

Comment: Hola, espero puedas leer de nuevo la pregunta les hice una modificaciones, ese día no analice bien tu respuesta, pero tengo es la duda, y es que si llamo el componente, pues et se *rendizara*, y solo quiero llamar la función, sin llamar a que el componente se *renderize*

Comment: Tienes que tener en cuenta la arquitectura de tu aplicacion. La razon de ser de tu componente. Si no quieres que tu componente se renderice, porque sería un React Component? Porque no una simple clase que ofrece servicios (funciones) a otras?. También podrías plantearte si la funcion que  quieres llamar no podría ser parte del mismo componente padre.

Comment: Muy cierto, buenas recomendaciones.

Answer (score 2):

> **Nota:** Los refs serán eliminados en versiones posteriores de React. Se aconseja evitar su uso lo más posibole.

Existen distintas formas de realizar lo que deseas. Algunas no tienen dependencias, como [redux](/questions/tagged/redux), otras no necesitan de librerías externas. En este último caso, puedes simplemente jugar con la forma de estructurar el flujo de información, por ejemplo derivarlo todo del componente padre o usar la nueva API `Context`.

Para no complicarte el asunto, te pondré una manera de hacerlo usando el componente Padre como proveedor.

```js
const styles = {
  child: {
    margin: '10px auto',
    padding: 20,
  },
  btn: {
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: 2,
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 14,
    marginLeft: 20,
    padding: '8px 12px',
  },
}

class Padre extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fn: {} // objeto de funciones
    }
    this.setFn = this.setFn.bind(this)
    this.execFn = this.execFn.bind(this)
  }
  
  setFn(name, fn) {
    this.setState({
      fn: { [name]: fn }
    })
  }
  
  execFn(name, ...args) {
    this.state.fn[name](args)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Hijo1 setFn={this.setFn} execFn={this.execFn} />
        <Hijo2 setFn={this.setFn} execFn={this.execFn} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

class Hijo1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: '' }
    this.funcionDos = this.funcionDos.bind(this)
    this.props.setFn('funcionDos', this.funcionDos)
  }
  
  funcionDos() {
    this.setState({ value: this.constructor.name })
    this.props.execFn('funcionTres')
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.child}>
        <span>Soy: {this.state.value}</span>
        <button style={styles.btn} onClick={this.funcionDos}>Descubrir</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Hijo2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: '' }
    this.funcionTres = this.funcionTres.bind(this)
    this.props.setFn('funcionTres', this.funcionTres)
  }
  
  funcionTres() {
    this.setState({ value: this.constructor.name })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.child}>Soy: {this.state.value}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Padre />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Hay múltiples formas de realizar esto, solo debes tener un poco de ingenio.